# 'pip' command doesn't execute in console2 but executes in windows command prompt

Tags: python, django

I have downloaded console2 for windows. Using that I wanted to setup django framework, but console2 couldn't recognize 'pip' as a command. When I tried the same command in windows command prompt, 'pip' was recognized by windows command prompt. Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `PATH` environment variable in console2. It should contains path to the `pip` executable.

In Windows Command-Prompt the syntax is `echo %PATH%`

To get a list of all environment variables enter the command `set`